# Wordpress Knowledge Base Plugin with lateral navigation

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress site using Knowledge Base Plugin and I need a lateral navigation that allows me to jump between post and categories, similar to the one in [Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/jira-application-video-tutorials-827114446.html).

Anyone could recommend a wordpress plugin that can use.

If it has the option of shows only post in the current category it should be great too.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress [Knowledge Base for Documentation and FAQs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/echo-knowledge-base/) has a paid-for add-on that has lateral navigation.